# Add custom HTML markup to Gutenberg RichText

Tags: javascript, block-editor

I'm using the `RichText` component to add some custom list on my Gutenberg Block.

```
function onItemsChange(items) {
    setAttributes({ items })
}

<RichText
    multiline="li"
    tagName="ul"
    value={attributes.items}
    onChange={onItemsChange}
    placeholder={__('Enter item list')}
/>
```

So this is rendering the next markup

```
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
</ul>
```

But I wanted to generate the next markup on every list item

```
<li class="list-item-class">
    <div class="flex">
        <!-- svg image -->
    </div>
    <p class="some-class">
          Item 1
    </p>
</li>
```

I was thinking of using some sort of replace on the `onItemsChange` function. Do you think this is a good approach? Or I'm doing it wrong? Any ideas? Maybe I need to use a [Dynamic Block](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/block-tutorial/creating-dynamic-blocks/)   **Yes I'm really lost here...**

For example **(I know this is not working)**:

```
function onItemsChange(items) {
    items = items.replaceAll('<li>', '<li class"list-item-class"><div class="flex"><!-- svg image --></div>');
    setAttributes({ items })
}
```

At this moment I was using the attributes:

```
items: {
    type: 'string',
    source: 'html',
    selector: 'ul',
},
```

But I think it would be better to use

```
items: {
    type: 'array',
    source: 'children',
    selector: 'ul',
},
```

Comment: What are you trying to implement that lead to the use of `<li>` tags and the richtext component? I'm questioning if the richtext component is the appropriate approach, if you have a list of items you should store its attribute as an array of items, you shouldn't be serialising it as `<li>` tags this way. String manipulation is not the answer

Comment: @TomJNowell you are right, it seems that using the richtext component is not the greatest approach here...

Comment: I'd say it is, but each individual item should be a richtext component, not the entire thing, aka 5 items = 5 richtext components, which also means your attribute or attributeS should be an array of some kind